# binding new DOM elements to viewmodel after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, viewmodel

I'm having troubles binding new DOM elements to my viewmodel. This elements are in a partial view loaded using an AJAX call (see the customizeQuote function below).

```
$(function () {
var mvcModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);

function QuoteViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.customizeQuote = function (quote) {
        self.selectedQuote = quote;

        //remove the disable attribute on all form controls before serializing data
        $(".step").each(function () {
            $(this).find('input, select').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

        //convert form data to an object 
        var formData = $('#etape').toObject();

        $.ajax("getSelectedQuote", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ model: self.selectedQuote, model1: formData }),

            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {

                $("#custom").html(result);
                $("#etape").formwizard("show", "customize");
                ko.applyBindings(self.selectedQuote, $("#covers"));

            }
        });
    }
}

var myViewModel = new QuoteViewModel();
var g = ko.mapping.fromJS(myViewModel, mvcModel);    
ko.applyBindings(g);
});
```

Here's the partial view html:

```
@model QuoteViewModel
<table id="covers">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ProductName
        </th>            
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: CoverQuotesViewModel">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: ProductName" />
        </td>          
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

the line:

```
ko.applyBindings(self.selectedQuote, $("#covers"));
```

triggers an error:

> "ko.applyBindings: first parameter should be your view model; second parameter should be a DOM node"

I'm fairly new to knockout and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$("#covers")` is not a DOM node though, it is an jQuery object. Perhaps try using this instead:

```
ko.applyBindings(self.selectedQuote, $("#covers")[0]);
```

The `[0]` will get the first matched element of the selector in the jquery object.

Comment: right you are ! Thanks for pointing this out, it's working now.